# manga where the hero defeats the demon army and after that goes to the demon kingdom to ask for job from the demon queen?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I only remember it vividly but in that manga, the hero is an android made in the past by the humans to defeat the demons who invaded the human world and the hero doesn't age. So now the world isn't that developed after the invasion of demons. And there is a demon queen and her generals' hero goes to demon world ask for job or to be her general I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *Yuusha, Yamemasu*

> After saving the world, the strongest hero who has no place to go anywhere, Leo. A power that is too strong can not enter the peaceful
> world …… Such a place of employment where he arrived – the former
> enemy, the Magus army!

[image]